# Wordpress buttons not inheriting custom CSS class

Tags: css, wordpress, inheritance

I am trying to add two buttons in a footer in Wordpress, using the Qode Bridge theme, on the site http://mygapyear.wpengine.com/. The code for the buttons (placed in the footer widget area) is as follows:

```
<div>
<div style="margin-top:10px">
[button class="newsletterButton"   icon="fa-arrow-right" target="_self" text="Newsletter signup" color="#ffffff" hover_color="#ffffff"]   
</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px">
[button class="newsletterButton" color="#ffffff" hover_color="#ffffff" icon="fa-arrow-right" target="_self" text="Request a Brochure"]
</div>
```

I have a couple of problems:

1. The buttons don't seem to be inheriting the class - inspecting them in the browser shows that they're both still in the qbutton class. I've placed CSS code for the class in both the Appearance > Editor section of WP, and the Qode Options > General > Custom CSS section:

   ```
   .qbutton .newsletterButton{ }
   ```
2. The "color" and "hover_color" attributes in the button shortcode don't seem to have any effect - is there a way to implement this in CSS to ensure that the colours are changed?
3. Is there a way to set button width as a percentage of the width of the div containing it?

Comment: I can't help with the Qode Bridge button shortcode issue, however the CSS should probably be `.qbutton.newsletterButton` if they get output into the same class attribute (I only see `class=qbutton`). To answer question 3, set the `a` element to `display: block` so you can apply widths.

Answer (score 1):

Karl is correct about the classes - if you are trying to reference the same element with two classes you want to use `.qbutton.newsletterButton { }`. If your issue is that you can't get the class you're specifying to be applied, maybe you could try to put the class on the div surrounding the button, like this:

```
<div style="margin-top:10px" class="newsletterButton">
    [button icon="fa-arrow-right" target="_self" ..etc]
</div>
```

And use the CSS

```
.newsletterButton .qbutton { }
```

You can style things on hover in CSS - try `.newsletterButton:hover { }`.

You can use percentage widths as well - just use the property `width: 50%;` (or whatever width you want) in your CSS. [Here's a good article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/) from CSS Tricks about percentage widths.